# math.net conversion of Matrix to Generic.Matrix<float>

Tags: f#, linear-algebra, math.net, mathnet-numerics

```
let v = [| 5.0; 2.0; 3.0; 11.0 |]
let m2 = new DenseMatrix(2, 2, v)
let invm = m2.Inverse()
let invt = m2.Transpose()
```

Here `m2` is a `Matrix`. However, `invm` and `invt` are `Generic.Matrix<float>`. Why this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly, because the signatures of `DenseMatrix.Inverse()` and `DenseMatrix.Transpose()` are

```
DenseMatrix.Inverse: unit -> Matrix<float>
DenseMatrix.Transpose: unit -> Matrix<float>
```

`Matrix` is an abstract class that provides common implementation of `Inverse` and `Transpose` methods for any matrix. Concrete derived subclasses `DenseMatrix`, `SparseMatrix`, and `DiagonalMatrix` just optimize way of storing matrix data depending on each use case.

You may upcast

```
let m2 = new DenseMatrix(2, 2, v) :> Matrix<float>
```

and manipulate with generic types after matrix creation.
You may want checking related topic [Matrix vs DenseMatrix](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/discussions/252623) for further details.

Comment: When you create the matrix using either the matrix function (`matrix [[ 5.0; 3.0]; [2.0; 11.0]]`) or one of the factory functions in the `DenseMatrix` module of the F# extensions, the matrix will automatically be of the generic type.